# R, in data.table, select some rows

Tags: r, data.table

I have this strange situation.  I am simply trying to select some rows from data.table.

```
dput(DT)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(10959, 10960, 10961, 10962, 
10963, 10966, 10967, 10968, 10969, 10970, 10974, 10975, 10976, 
10977, 10980, 10981, 10982, 10983, 10984, 10987), class = "Date"), 
    A = c(51.502148, 47.567955, 44.61731, 42.918453, 46.494991, 
    49.311516, 48.640915, 47.657368, 48.372677, 48.909157, 51.144493, 
    50.071529, 48.730328, 49.177395, 48.998569, 48.417381, 48.864449, 
    48.953861, 48.685623, 47.344421), AA = c(96.840897, 97.561798, 
    103.329002, 101.598839, 101.406601, 101.214363, 100.397339, 
    99.820618, 97.802101, 96.120003, 93.717003, 93.813118, 88.093979, 
    90.400864, 88.045921, 86.748299, 85.450684, 84.489479, 83.287979, 
    83.432159), AAC = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), AACG = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fa9640148e0>, sorted = "Date")

StartDate <- as.Date("2000-01-05")
TestDates <- c(StartDate,
               StartDate + duration(6, units = "day"),
               StartDate + duration(2, units = "week"))

DT[Date %in% TestDates, ]  # works well here.
```

The real data of "DT" has 20 million rows.  Using this same block of codes, R reported:

Empty data.table (0 rows and 7347 cols)

Does anyone know how to pick rows using a vector, in a more reliable way?

Comment: What is `class(DT$Date)` in your real data?

Comment: > class(Zin_Info$Date)
[1] "Date"

Comment: Are you sure the `TestDates` are present in your real `DT` ? Can you manually view some of them? If yes, Can you subset only that specific portion of the data to provide us  reproducible data.

Comment: Yes, `TestDates` are present.  The link below is from `DT <- Zin_Info[1:20, 1:5]`: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jya4TVcyWyl17lq4UmLQTYYnaakKkw9D/view?usp=sharing (Oops!  Sorry, Let me redo it.)

Comment: Here is the portion of the data, in CSV.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eTza3PvKz9k74F29Qf2m__p7Qbjy1B7a/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You should provide the minimum sample data that can reproduce your problem. As you say, your current sample data works well.

Comment: It works well on the csv data that you shared as well. These are my steps : `DT <- read_csv('Zin_Info_Sample2.csv');setDT(DT);DT[Date %in% TestDates]` and it gives me 3 rows as expected.

Comment: Yes, I know the sample data works.  I am still trying different things on the real data.

Comment: I found the problem.  In `TestDates <- c(StartDate + duration(1, units = "day"))`, when I change the "day" to "year", the result start to look funny.  Then the DT subset code stop working.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. In this line of code:

```
StartDate <- as.Date("2000-01-05")
```

I was trying to set the base date and then use the following codes to get different dates.

```
TestDates <- c(StartDate,
               StartDate + duration(6, units = "day"),
               StartDate + duration(2, units = "week"))
```

But using `duration` is wrong.  Instead, I need:

```
TestDates <- c(StartDate,
               StartDate + days(6),
               StartDate + weeks(2))
```

In my case, I need to get data from different years, for example, 2000-01-01 and 2020-01-01.  Using periods like `seconds`, `minutes`, `hours`, `days`, `months`, `weeks` and `years` work on human level and I do not need to worry about leap years.  For example:

```
StartDate <- ymd("2020-01-01") # note, 2020 is leap year

StartDates + duration(1, units = "year")
>[1] "2020-12-31 06:00:00 UTC"

StartDates + years(1)
>[1] "2021-01-01"
```